# How to route metabase through a certain domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, metabase

I am relatively new to Metabase. I want to set up an EC2 instance to have my custom website `www.*.com` display the Metabase homepage so I can follow the corresponding setup. Please can you advise on how this can be done? I have tried and researched but not gotten what I actually want.

Please ask questions if you do not understand any part of the question.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to point the domain name to the IP Address of the EC2 machine, using the Domain Name System (DNS), most likely with an "A record"

By default, your EC2 instance, will have a different IP address if you stop/start it, so you should use an Elastic IP Address to give you a static IP

You will need to read your DNS host's documentation to figure out exactly how to do that. If you happen to use AWS's Route 53 DNS service, here is the appropriate [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/getting-started.html)

Comment: I have been able to access the metabase using the ec2 IP but how do I ensure the IP is attached to the preferred URL?

Comment: @ArogbonloSamuel that requires setting a DNS record

Comment: Well, from the recent progress, I need an SSL cert to update the .conf file for the EC2 instance. Now after creating the public cert, is there how to download the file and private key for use?